# Select a repeated element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, counting

I want to select all elements that repeat 4 times in the list. I propose this code

```
list = {a, a, a, b, c, a, b, b, b, e};

elementsplus4 = Select[list, Count[list, #] == 4 &];
```

I obtain:

```
{a, a, a, b, a, b, b, b}
```

How can I obtain just `{a,b}`

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates`

Comment: `Cases[Tally[list], {i_, 4}:>i]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may use Tally to finish the task as follows:

```
Cases[Tally[list], {x_, 4} :> x]
```

the result will be {a,b}.

Comment: Yup, that's the one. +1

Comment: Cases[Tally[list], {x_, 4} -> x] seems to work too.

Answer (score 9):

The code given by Rojo and sunt05 is almost surely the cleanest:

```
Cases[Tally @ list, {x_, 4} :> x]
```

However, here are some other possibilities:

```
Cases[Split @ Sort @ list, {x_, _, _, _} :> x]

Cases[Split @ Sort @ list, {Repeated[x_, {4}]} :> x]

Cases[Last @ Reap[Sow[1, list], _, {#, Tr@#2} &], {x_, 4} :> x]

Module[{c},
  c[_] = 0;
  Scan[c[#]++ &, list];
  Cases[DownValues[c], (_@_@x_ :> 4) :> x]
]
```

### Performance

Interestingly, some of these may be significantly faster than `Tally` in certain cases:

```
list = FromCharacterCode /@ RandomInteger[15000, 100000];

Cases[Tally @ list, {x_, 4} :> x]                               // Timing // First

Cases[Last @ Reap[Sow[1, list], _, {#, Tr@#2} &], {x_, 4} :> x] // Timing // First

Module[{c},
 c[_] = 0;
 Scan[c[#]++ &, list];
 Cases[DownValues[c], (_@_@x_ :> 4) :> x]
] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.546
>
> 0.109
>
> 0.2622
> ```

---

Since it seems to be only in the case of String objects that `Sow`/`Reap` is faster, for clarity one might write the second method as:

```
stringTally = Last @ Reap[Sow[1, #], _, {#, Tr@#2} &] &;

Cases[stringTally @ list, {x_, 4} :> x] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.103
> ```

---

### Addendum

The OP wrote: "I want to list all elements that appear at least four times."  In light of that here are all the methods modified accordingly:

```
stringTally = Last @ Reap[Sow[1, #], _, {#, Tr@#2} &] &;

Cases[stringTally @ list, {x_, n_} /; n >= 4 :> x]

Cases[Split @ Sort @ list, {x_, _, _, __} :> x]

Cases[Split @ Sort @ list, {Repeated[x_, {4, ∞}]} :> x]

Cases[Last @ Reap[Sow[1, list], _, {#, Tr@#2} &], {x_, n_} /; n >= 4 :> x]

Module[{c},
  c[_] = 0;
  Scan[c[#]++ &, list];
  Cases[DownValues[c], (_@_@x_ :> n_) /; n >= 4 :> x]
]
```

Comment: How can we change `Cases[Last @ Reap[Sow[1, list], _, {#, Tr@#2} &], {x_, 4} :> x]` when we need to select the elements repated greater than 4 times ?

Comment: @developer2000 just change the `4` in `{x_, 4} :> x`, as you would with the `Tally` solution.

Comment: I think that you did not understand me. I would select the elements that repeated 4 times, 5 times, 6 times and so on (greater than 4). I think that I can use `Table[Cases[stringTally @ list, {x_, i} :> x],{i,4,n}]`  but is there any other pretty solution?

Comment: @developer2000 Oh, that was not clear.  Do you mean that you wish to list the elements that appear four times separately from those that appear five times, etc., or list all elements that appear *at least* four times?

Comment: I want to list all elements that appear at least four times. sorry for the bed english.

Comment: @developer2000 See my updated answer.

Comment: where you are using `Tr@` to sum  a list of `1`'s wouldn't it be even faster to use `Length@`?

Comment: @george2079 Yes, I think it probably would be.  (I can't test it at the moment.)  `Tr` is habit from totaling binary lists.

Answer (score 4):

```
DeleteDuplicates[Select[list, Count[list, #] == 4 &]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or be lazy and just run the set theory-inspired Union[] command over the result of your initial computation, provided that the initial one yields the results you listed -- it doesn't for me.

Comment: sometimes being lazy is a good choice!! I know this solution!