# How do Reap and Sow work in this context

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, symbols

I have a list  of points in 3D and I need to count how many times each point is repeated. For a similar problem with a list of characters many different solutions have been proposed in this post: [solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40317/select-a-repeated-element-in-a-list). Among those, I have here select this solution which is faster:

```
stringTally = Last @ Reap[Sow[1, #], _, {#, Tr@#2} &] &;
(* to be used as in this example to catch 4 repetitions *)
(* Cases[ stringTally @ list, {x_, 4}:>x] *)
```

Unfortunately I cannot understand how `Reap` works in `stringTally`. I tried to decompose it but the use of two pure functions make the expression a little bit complicated.

Comment: http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/04/20/mathematica-qa-sow-reap-and-parallel-programming/

Comment: @PatrickStevens, I know how does it work and I have already read this blog.

Comment: If you use `Trace` on your list of character example (e.g. `Cases[stringTally@list, {x_, 4} :> x]` and at the same time carefully read the documentation on a separate window you should see how it works.

Comment: You might, I believe, also write `stringTally` a bit differently: `stringTally = Last@Reap[Sow[1, ##], _, {#1, Tr@#2} &] &`. So the `##` will take the list as it is (with each element being a tag for `Sow` and the `#1,#2` in the pure function at the end work on each collection as part or the `Reap`. `Tr@#2` will simply give the total for a vector and each collection will have a number of 1s for each instance as its second part. Hope that helps -- sometimes Mma is very compact and fast but not quite readable for humans...

Comment: @gwr, there is only one argument (to `stringTally`) so `#` vs `##` makes no difference.

Comment: @george2079 Yes, I know, but it makes a 'visual' difference and thus helps to distinguish the different slots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can see from this expression

```
Reap[Sow[1, #] & /@ {1, 1, 2, 3}, _, f]
(* Out: {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {f[1, {1, 1}], f[2, {1}], f[3, {1}]}} *)
```

how `Sow` and `Reap` interact in general. In this example `f` is `{#, Tr@#2} &`. `Tr` in this context works just like `Total` but it can be faster. But the sum of the second part is just the sum of `1`s, the number of times that the particular tag has been sown (because `1` is sown each time).

Please ask questions if you want a more thorough explanation.

Comment: The only thing I'd mention is that `Reap` is of the form `Reap[expr, pattern, function]` and here the pattern is `_` which will match anything. `Sow` then organizes by tag and `Reap` applies the final function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40317/select-a-repeated-element-in-a-list) you supplied indicates that the use of the `Sow` and `Reap` approach performs better than `Tally` when strings are involved.

However, to count the number of occurrences in your list of 3D points, `Tally` is actually better.

```
list = Partition[RandomInteger[15000, 300000], 3];

Tally@list // Timing // First
```

0.078 seconds on my machine while

```
Last@Reap[Sow[1, list], _, {#, Tr@#2} &] // Timing // First
```

takes 1.59 seconds.