# How to remove the item that is repeated?

Tags: pattern-matching

If i have a

```
list={m,n,p,q,q,r,l,l}
```

how can i remove the repeated item with pattern matching so i would have

```
modifiedlist={m,n,p,r}?
```

Comment: {a, b, a} - is `a` repeated here?

Comment: @Kuba yes it is.

Comment: Closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40317/5478

Comment: Also related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107483/106

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Keys@Select[Counts[list], # == 1 &]
```

> {m, n, p, r}

Also:

```
Select[list, Count[list, #] == 1 &]
Select[list, Counts[list][#] == 1 &]
Flatten[Cases[Split[Sort[list]], {_}]]
Flatten[DeleteCases[Split[Sort[list]], {_, __}]]
Flatten[Select[Split[Sort[list]], Length@# == 1 &]]
SequenceReplace[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[Repeated[b_, {2, Infinity}], a_]} :> a]
```

Comment: very nice i added {m,n,p,q,q,r,l,l} /. a_List :> Select[a, Count[a, #] == 1 &]

Comment: @user49047, `Select[a, Count[a, #] == 1 &]` gives you the result directly; you don't need to use `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: The method using `Counts` is probably the best way, since you only have to traverse the whole list once.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, excellent point.

Answer (score 6):

```
First /@ Select[Tally@list, Last@# == 1 &]
```

> {m, n, p, r}

or

```
First /@ Cases[Tally@list, {_, 1}]
```

> {m, n, p, r}

Comment: `Cases[]` seems to be fastest so far on large lists.  `Cases[Tally@list, {_, 1}][[All, 1]]` is about 10% faster on unpacked arrays, slightly slower on packed arrays.